# On what basis do we decide whether to use GDR or CU?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, patching

I have installed sql server 2019 in Jan 2021.

We are planning to patch the sqlserver and from this link there are 2 options:

1. GDR
2. CU

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I couldn't find clear reference to understand the basis on how to decide whether to choose GDR or CU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDR stands for General Distribution Release, whilst CU stands for Cumulative Update. The [difference](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-1636) is that GDR patches contain only security fixes, and CUs include security fixes and functional fixes.

As for which patch branch to follow, Microsoft's own advice from the forementioned page says:

> For any given baseline, either the GDR or CU updates could be options
> (see below).
>
> - If SQL Server installation is at a baseline version, you can choose    either the GDR or CU update.
> - If SQL Server installation has intentionally only installed past GDR updates, then choose to install the GDR update package.
> - If SQL Server installation has intentionally installed previous CU updates, then chose to install the CU security update package.

As a rule of a thumb, install Cumulative Updates unless you know that GDR is required. Please read CU patch notes before installing, as they do change SQL Server's behaviour.

Comment: @variable Baseline is the version without any updates. Since GDR contains _only_ security fixes, picking it will exclude any functional updates. Please take a look at recent CU fix list to see what kind of issues are being fixed.

Comment: A minor, but important clarification: GDR updates are a subset that will only include the _most critical_ fixes. They are usually security related, but could be other wide-ranging critical issues. There will be security fixes that only go to CU & not GDR.  This is designed to allow folks to push out those most critical fixes by reducing test surface area.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're specifically required to use GDR, go with CU. The fixes and feature updates in CUs may be useful "non-critical fixes" and can include performance fixes. In almost all cases, you want the ability to benefit from these non-critical fixes. In my experience, the install base for CU instances is so much larger that it is the presumed default.

The only time I've encountered GDR is when a vendor, customer, or contract specifically required that the instance of SQL Server have it. Those specific applications require that the RDBMS be as maximally code-stable as possible. The software may require validation, verification, or satisfy some other whatever technical, regulatory, legal, or contractual obligations.